# find count of element over multiple array

Tags: python, list

Given two list I need to make a third list which contains elements that occur only twice in over all list 1 and list 2.
How to do it efficienlty with reasonable time and space complexity ?

my solution:
using dictionary:

```
from collections import defaultdict


L=['a','b','c','d','a','d','e','e','g','h']
K=['a','g','i','g','g','i','r','r']

d=defaultdict(int)

for i in L:
    d[i]+=1
for j in K:
    d[j]+=1

print d
result=[]
for key,val in d.iteritems():
  if val == 2:
     result.append(key)

print result
```

My desired output would be:

```
['e', 'd', 'i', 'r']
```

Can I get a better pythonic solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Please give an expected output sample for the same.

Comment: ['e', 'd', 'i', 'r']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the collection's counter class to simplify the code:

```
from collections import Counter
...
d = Counter(L+K) #we are combining to process both at once
```

Additionally, you can combine lines by doing a conditional for loop. So only if the value is 2, then we will append it to our array.

```
L=['a','b','c','d','a','d','e','e','g','h']
K=['a','g','i','g','g','i','r','r']
print [k for k, v in Counter(L+K).iteritems() if v == 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use python `Counter` for getting count of each word in the list. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects

```
>>> L=['a','b','c','d','a','d','e','e','g','h']
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(L)
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2, 'd': 2, 'e': 2, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'g': 1, 'h': 1})
```

After doing this iterate over counter object and add elements to third list which have value 2.

Answer (score 0):

This will work well with respect to space complexity, it's also pythonic, but I'm not too sure about the run time

```
set([x for x in L.extend(K) if L.extend(K).count(x) == 2])
```

Notice that this returns a set and not a list!

Comment: This computes `L.extend(K)` twice, though. Add an extra line to compute that once.

Comment: Also, this mutates `L`.  The original question didn't _forbid_ that, but there's no reason to change inputs if you don't need to (especially when the question's focus is time and space efficiency).